# How do I extract only "message" field values from kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

How do I extract only "message" field values from kibana?

[image]
-> Looking at the picture, I want to erase the _index, _type, _id, and _score scores, and print out only the value of the "message" field in the _source.

I searched Google, but I couldn't find a way.
Please teach me the way.

It's the way I tried it.

```
 GET 0503instgram_csv/_search
    {
      "_source": [
        "message"
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [response filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering) to just show the `message` field in the response

```
http://localhost:9200/index-name/_search?_source=message&filter_path=hits.hits._source
```

Comment: It's the price I really want.
We appreciate your pointing it out to us.

Comment: Do you happen to know the site address that contains the content?

I want to study DSL more deeply.

Comment: @인제김 you can refer to the official documentation of Elasticsearch --> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/elasticsearch-intro.html

Comment: We appreciate your pointing it out to us.

Can I ask you one more question?
Do you know how to store only the extracted values in a different index?

Comment: @인제김 you can use the reindex API --> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-filter-source